# Nested Rest resource throws constraint violation in Jhipster

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jhipster

I have a nested resource like this:

```
@GetMapping("/tour-requests/{tourRequestId}/tour-request-messages")
@Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN})

public ResponseEntity<List<TourRequestMessageDTO>> getTourRequestMessagesForTourRequest(
        @PathVariable("tourRequestId") long tourRequestId,
        TourRequestMessageCriteria criteria) {
...
}
```

When I call this resource, for example with `GET api/tour-requests/1301/tour-request-messages` I get unexpected error:

```
{
    "type": "https://zalando.github.io/problem/constraint-violation",
    "title": "Constraint Violation",
    "status": 400,
    "path": "/api/tour-requests/1301/tour-request-messages",
    "violations": [
        {
            "field": "tourRequestId",
            "message": "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'io.github.jhipster.service.filter.LongFilter' for property 'tourRequestId'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'io.github.jhipster.service.filter.LongFilter' for property 'tourRequestId': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
        }
    ],
    "message": "error.validation"
}
```

I tried to debug this, it seems that the exception is happening before the method is called-

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I tried with JHipster 4.14.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the search criteria has hijacked the path parameter `tourRequestId`, as it happen to be also a possible search parameter of the generated QueryService. 
That it is why it tried to convert the `tourRequestId` parameter to `LongFilter`.

Renaming the path variable to ìd` did also not helped, but after renaming it to something different, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I've also hit this problem, but my choice was to remove the field from child's `pt.up.hs.project.service.dto.ChildCriteria`. When the resource is always nested, it just does not make sense to allow querying by the field which is also specified in the path.